# django: IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture '/app/fixtures.json': Could not load auth.User(pk=1): duplicate key

Tags: python, django, heroku, fixtures

I run the fixtures locally and everything is alright.

On heroku, i run `heroku run python manage.py loaddata fixtures.json` and it failed

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture '/app/fixtures.json': Could not load auth.User(pk=1): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_profile_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already exists.
```

i have logined with admin and delete all users and posts on heroku. what could I do?

Comment: Did you clear the `users_profile` table too?

Comment: What do you mean by clearing? I logged in as admin and delete everything, the profile should be cascadedly deleted

Comment: I didn't know if your profile/user relationship was set up to cascade, sorry. You could try running [`python manage.py flush`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#flush) before `loaddata` to completely clear out all data in your DB

Comment: Still.. `Could not load auth.User(pk=1): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_profile_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.`

Comment: Looks slightly different this time, `users_profile_pkey` constraint violated this time instead of `users_profile_user_id_key`. If all data has been cleared from the DB then it seems like it may be a problem with the fixture, can you shae the fixture or part of it? The only other thing I can think of is to run the SQL returned by [`python manage.py sqlsequencereset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#sqlsequencereset) manually to ensure it's not an issue with your sequences

Comment: i `dumpdata` then flushed then `loaddata`. it shows `Problem installing fixture '/home/chi/internal-website/datafixtures.json': Could not load auth.User(pk=1): UNIQUE constraint failed: users_profile.user_id` how is it different

Comment: i dont know how to run spl. im trying django_seed. the thing is, i would like to populate the data base not with random but my own initial values

Comment: You're just dumping the entire DB and then loading it again? The [`--natural-foreign`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-dumpdata-natural-foreign) and/or the [`--natural-primary`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-dumpdata-natural-primary) args may get around the issue as you wouldn't be serializing the pks when dumping the data. How much data do you have, if not a great amount there are other options

Comment: Are you using the same database both locally and on heroku?

Comment: i use the built in, sqlite for local, and postgres by heroku. it is not a db, it is sample db